# Dynamic Tree in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tree

Could anybody help me doing this in c# and allow the user to add or remove nodes or is there any library.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class which inherits a panel, then create a invisible TreeView (to store the data) and override OnPaint. Below is some sample code, that generates some circles with text, but there are no lines between them. Also the part the draws the child nodes will not generate more than four rows but it could be modified to generate more.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class BinaryTreeView : Panel
{   
    public BinaryTreeView()
    {
        this.Location = new Point(2, 2);
        this.Size = new Size(500, 400);
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.Font = new Font(this.Font.Name, 21f, FontStyle.Bold);
    }

    public void AddParent(string nodeName)
    {
        binaryTreeViewData.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Name = nodeName });
        this.Refresh();
    }

    public void Add(string nodeName, string parentNode)
    {
        try { binaryTreeViewData.Nodes.Find(parentNode, true)[0].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Name = nodeName }); } catch { }
        this.Refresh();
    }

    public void Remove(string nodeName)
    {
        // find and remove code.
        this.Refresh();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        List<TreeNode> childNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        for (int i = (binaryTreeViewData.Nodes.Count - 1); i > -1; i--)
        {
            Point nodePos = new Point(((this.Width - (55 * binaryTreeViewData.Nodes.Count)) / 2) + (i * 55), 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 3), new Rectangle(nodePos.X, nodePos.Y, 50, 50));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(binaryTreeViewData.Nodes[i].Name, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), nodePos.X + 11, nodePos.Y + 9);

            foreach (TreeNode childNode in binaryTreeViewData.Nodes[i].Nodes)
            {
                childNodes.Add(childNode);
            }
        }

        // Child node drawing part.
        List<TreeNode> childNodes2 = new List<TreeNode>();
        childNodes.Reverse();

        for (int i = (childNodes.Count - 1); i > -1; i--)
        {
            Point nodePos = new Point(((this.Width - (55 * childNodes.Count)) / 2) + (i * 55), 65);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 3), new Rectangle(nodePos.X, nodePos.Y, 50, 50));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(childNodes[i].Name, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), nodePos.X + 11, nodePos.Y + 9);

            foreach (TreeNode childNode in childNodes[i].Nodes)
            {
                childNodes2.Add(childNode);
            }
        }

        List<TreeNode> childNodes3 = new List<TreeNode>();
        childNodes2.Reverse();

        for (int i = (childNodes2.Count - 1); i > -1; i--)
        {
            Point nodePos = new Point(((this.Width - (55 * childNodes2.Count)) / 2) + (i * 55), 125);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 3), new Rectangle(nodePos.X, nodePos.Y, 50, 50));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(childNodes2[i].Name, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), nodePos.X + 11, nodePos.Y + 9);

            foreach (TreeNode childNode in childNodes2[i].Nodes)
            {
                childNodes3.Add(childNode);
            }
        }

        childNodes3.Reverse();

        for (int i = (childNodes3.Count - 1); i > -1; i--)
        {
            Point nodePos = new Point(((this.Width - (55 * childNodes3.Count)) / 2) + (i * 55), 185);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 3), new Rectangle(nodePos.X, nodePos.Y, 50, 50));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(childNodes3[i].Name, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), nodePos.X + 11, nodePos.Y + 9);
        }
    }

    private TreeView binaryTreeViewData = new TreeView();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
BinaryTreeView BinaryTreeViewExample = new BinaryTreeView();
BinaryTreeViewExample.AddParent("A");

BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("D", "A");
BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("J", "D");
BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("O", "J");
BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("N", "J");
BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("I", "D");
BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("H", "D");

BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("C", "A");
BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("G", "C");
BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("M", "G");
BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("L", "G");

BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("B", "A");
BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("F", "B");
BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("E", "B");
BinaryTreeViewExample.Add("K", "E");

...Controls.Add(BinaryTreeViewExample);
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Note:** You have to add elements in reverse, because the drawing function draws the nodes in reverse.

Comment: Fantastic Answer